# Access to datagrid values from another form

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I want to access datagrid values from another form. What should I do?

I use this method in the parent form, but it doesn't work:

```
    public static int indicebis(DataGridView dataGridView1)
    {
        string titRicerca = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Column2"].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
        string datRicerca = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Column4"].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < DBList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (DBList[i].Titolo.ToUpper() == titRicerca && DBList[i].Data.ToUpper() == datRicerca)
            {
                x = i;
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: You need to be more specific.  What doesn't work?  How do you pass your reference for the DataGridView values to your second form, and how does that form try to use them?

Comment: Form1 f = new Form1();
                Form1.DBList[Form1.indicebis(f.DataGridView1)] = temp;
//temp is a class, DBList is formed by temp

Comment: DataGridView1 is a method in Form1
public DataGridView DataGridView1 { get; set; }

Comment: exception not handled 'System.NullReferenceException' in CatMedia.exe this is the error what i get

Comment: I don't see the code that brings up the second form. Is the method you posted supposed to do that? Please show the code that brings up the second form, and then show how you try to access the data in the second form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I the absence of more code I'll give you a general formula for making data from one form available to another form.  Assuming that you call the second form as the result of a button click on the parent form:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SecondForm form = new SecondForm())
        {
            form.titRicerca = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Column2"].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
            form.datRicerca = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Column4"].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
            form.ShowDialog();

            // after you have exited the second form, form.titRicerca and form.datRicerca will
            // still be available for as long as you are in this using clause.  Assign them
            // elsewhere if you need the parent form to access them
        }
    }
```

Your secondary form would have these public variables:

```
public partial class SecondForm : Form
{
    public string titRicerca = null;
    public string datRicerca = null;
}
```